# plot moving and rotating polygon over the static map

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a following setup: a tkinter app has a static real-life map, which is plotted via plotting two geodataframes (for land and water), both with a uniformed shape:

```
def make_figure(self, map):
    land = map.land.to_crs(epsg=4326)
    water = map.water.to_crs(epsg=4326)
    xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = map.contour.bounds

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 9), dpi=100)
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.01, right=0.99, top=0.99, bottom=0.01)
    plt.axis('off')
    ax.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
    ax.set_ylim([ymin,ymax])

    water.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='lightskyblue')
    land.plot(ax=ax, edgecolor='grey', facecolor='cornsilk', linewidth=1, alpha=1)
    return fig, ax
```

Then returned figure and axes are embedded into tkinter canvas in a standard way:

```
    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, draw_frame)
    self.canvas.draw()
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, draw_frame)
```

There is also some model inside this tkinter's app, which does all agent-based operations like moving and rotating and updates their shapes on each step. What I want to do is to have an as much as possible smooth dynamic agents' shapes updating. At the moment the only working solution for me looks like this (we receive list of Shapely `shapes` via `self.model` object, after it does `step()` method inside tkinter's loop):

```
    def update_agents_shapes(self):
        shapes = self.model.get_new_shapes()
        self.ax.patches = []
        for shape in shapes:
            patch = PolygonPatch(shape, fc="green", ec="green", alpha=0.5, zorder=2)
            self.ax.add_patch(patch)
```

What it does: it deletes all the patches (descartes `PolygonPatch`es) from axes (in which there is also a static map drawn above) and adds them one more time, recreating with an updated shape.

This solution works, but notably freezes my tkinter app. I understand, that it should be possible easier with the matplotlib animation and basically my shapes are rectangles, which are rotating and moving each step. Basically I know the new coordinates of the centroid and a new heading angle, that's enough to rebuild the shape.

My questions are: 1) how to do the animation over the static map, if you receive updates of your dynamic object's shapes from the "outside" and receive preferably as Shapely object? and 2) how to embed this solution into the tkinter app with the best performance? My option is bad at performance, mainly it is very slow reacting to pan/zoom

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to add this as a comment, but assuming you send each of the agent based model timestep/s to completion, it will freeze the GUI until that process is finished.  You will need to thread the agent based side of things if you don't want the GUI to freeze.

Secondly, should you want the plot to update continuously at each timestep, I suggest you look into blitting for the plot ([docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/blitting.html) here).  This will capture the map elements of the plot, and then only updates the agents at each timestep (saving the time of replotting the base map).  Depending on how many agents etc you have, this may solve the speed issue.  A word of warning however, blitting and threading [do not like each other](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13293) - you'll have to figure out how to get the plot information from the thread to the main GUI thread.